# Subject RxJS not updating variable in another component

Tags: angular

In this, I am practicing on **Subject** command. on inputpage subject is working. but when I navigate to page1 via routerlink. I don't see updated value of the name. I am not sure if it's working or not. For now, my guess is that whenever I navigate away from the input page my variable **profile** reset on page1 component file?

**page1.component.html**

```
<div class="container page1">
  <p>{{profile.name}}</p>
</div>
```

**page1.component.ts**

```
import { InputpageComponent } from './../inputpage/inputpage.component';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-page1',
  templateUrl: './page1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page1.component.css']
})
export class Page1Component implements OnInit {
  profile: Profile = {name: "sanam", email: "sdasdsdas"};

  constructor(private inputPage: InputpageComponent) {
    this.inputPage.subject.subscribe(dataRec => { 
    this.profile = dataRec.value;
    console.log("Updated");
    })
   }

  ngOnInit() { }  
}
```

**inputpage.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from "rxjs";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-inputpage',
  templateUrl: './inputpage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./inputpage.component.css']
})
export class InputpageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  subject = new Subject<any> ();

  btnClicked(data){
    this.subject = data.value;
    console.log(this.subject);

  }

  ngOnInit() { }
```

**inputpage.component.html**

```
<div class="container inputPage">
  <h3>Submit Form</h3>
  <div class="formsbt">
    <form (ngSubmit)="btnClicked(f)" #f="ngForm">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input class="formsbt" type="text" id="name" ngModel name="name">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input class="formsbt" type="text" id="email" ngModel name="email">
      <button class="formsbt" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"  > Submit </button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <h1>{{subject.name}}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: This.subject.next(data.value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a service where you want to have your "data logic", then inject that service into the components where you need those data.

A service should be injected instead of `private inputPage: InputpageComponent` in the `page1.component.ts`.

Another thing is that when you subscribe to a `Subject` you won't get the last data if the subscription was done after the data were emitted. You should use `BehaviorSubject` instead. To be sure that you're getting the latest data in every subscription.

Also, if you want to pass new data to a Subject or BehaviorSubject, you're not assigning it but calling the `next()` method:

```
this.subject.next(data.value);
```

Comment: yes, I understand that how you use service to distribute data. In this, I was trying to figure out how to send data from component to another component (for example sending input data to a service file.)

Comment: For sending data between siblings you can either use services or a state management system (e.g. NgRx). For passing data between parents and children you can use `@Input` and `@Output`